# Difference between SCOPE and DATA_SOURCE in Fitness API

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-fitness-api

I'm working on fetching heart rate data from Google Fitness API using python and I would like to know what is the difference between hear rate SCOPE "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.read" and DATA_SOURCE "derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_rate_bpm" under "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read" SCOPE?
I search and did not find answer.  Google documentation is not clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can the scopes and the list of what they do here [Fitness API, v1](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#fitness)

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read Use Google Fit to see and store your physical activity data
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.read   See your heart rate data in Google Fit. I consent to Google sharing my heart rate information with this app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  But is not it both gives heart rate readings? In other words, can I use DATA_SOURCE "derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_rate_bpm" with  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.read" SCOPE as well as "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read" SCOPE?

Comment: Not sure I understand. activity read gives access to read all activates.  it would give access to read heart_rate.